# Implement pipe puzzle in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement the pipe puzzle game in C but I'm having an issue with how to structure the data to reflect the map.

This is the default map size:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 20
```

This is my Map struct:

```
typedef struct {
    Cell cells[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];

}Map;
```

This is my Cell struct:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int coord_x;
    unsigned int coord_y;
    Tube tube;

}Cell;
```

This is my Tube struct:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int direction[4]; //[0, 0, 0, 0] -> Up, Right, Down, Left
    unsigned int type; //0 -> Empty, 1 -> Start, 2 -> End, 3 -> Tube
    BOOL hasWater;

}Tube;
```

If I wanted to create an example map with the given MAX_SIZE, how would I go about to do this?

I've tried something like this but it's not working:

```
Map map = { {Cell.tube.direction[0, 0, 1, 0]}, ... }
```

(I know this might give me an error because the Cell is not initialized, but I need a way to tell exactly what each cell is, in terms of it's direction)

**EDIT: I think this image describes what I'm trying to do a little better.
[image: game]

I'm trying to do an example map already with the correct path, so the first square would be something like `cell[0][0].tube.direction[0, 1, 0, 0]` where the direction would mean it would be open to the right.

Am I in the right path?

Comment: `Map` already contains the Cell array of the correct size - you just need `Map map`,

Comment: @pm100 That was a mistake that I wrote here, that's not the actual code but I still need a way to say that that Cell needs to have those directions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is "If I wanted to create an example map with the given MAX_SIZE, how would I go about to do this?"

Just write `Map map = {};` in your `main` function or at the top level of your program, and it will create a struct named `map` of type `Map` and it will zero-initialize all the members of the struct.

You can set the members of the `direction` array with simple code like:

```c
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
map.cells[x][y].tube.direction[0] = 0;
map.cells[x][y].tube.direction[1] = 1;
map.cells[x][y].tube.direction[2] = 0;
map.cells[x][y].tube.direction[3] = 0;
```

If you want to set all the elements of a Tube struct on one line, you can use compound literal syntax:

```c
map.cells[x][y].tube = (Tube){ { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, 17, true };
```

Note that it is kind of redundant for a `Cell` to hold a copy of its own coordinates, since its coordinates should probably just be determined by where it is in the `cells` 2D array.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify some more things.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to set all 4 elements of the `direction` array for one of the cells, and you want the second element to be 1, and all the others to be 0.  Is that correct?  Will you accept this answer if I show how to do that?  I don't like shifting goal posts so I just want to know what you're looking for exactly.

Comment: Yes that's the gist of it, basically the elements of `direction` determine what side of the pipe/cell is open to the other ones

Comment: OK, please see the information I added to my answer and the click the checkmark to accept.  I added two blocks of code showing how to set all 4 elements of the direction array to your desired values, so you can pick whichever one works better for you.

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thanks!